# Fgets writes different strings from the same file in Linux and Windows

Tags: c, linux, fgets

I've just come across an issue where I was jumping between valgrind in Linux and other testing in Windows cmd.

I'm reading a certain line from a file like this:

```
fgets(buf, MAX_LINE_LEN, f_input);
```

Of course, buf is the size MAX_LINE_LEN + 1, but I digress.

This is the output of

```
printf("String length: %u; Contents: ", strlen(buf));
for (usint i = 0; i < strlen(buf); i++)
  printf("%x ", buf[i]);
puts(";");
```

in Windows:

```
String length: 14; Contents: 41 6e 64 72 65 6a 20 50 6c 61 76 6b 61 a ;
String length: 22; Contents: 41 6e 6e 61 20 4d 61 72 69 61 20 43 69 63 6d 61 6e 63 6f 76 61 a ;
String length: 25; Contents: 4d 61 72 69 61 20 52 61 7a 75 73 6f 76 61 20 4d 61 72 74 61 6b 6f 76 61 a ;
String length: 24; Contents: 4d 69 6c 61 6e 20 52 61 73 74 69 73 6c 61 76 20 50 6f 6b 6f 6a 6e 79 a ;
String length: 21; Contents: 4d 69 6c 65 6e 61 20 53 65 64 6d 69 6b 72 61 73 6b 6f 76 61 a ;
String length: 15; Contents: 56 69 6e 63 65 6e 74 20 53 69 6b 75 6c 61 a ;
String length: 17; Contents: 56 69 6e 63 65 6e 74 20 76 61 6e 20 47 6f 67 68 a ;
```

and in Linux:

```
String length: 15; Contents: 41 6e 64 72 65 6a 20 50 6c 61 76 6b 61 d a ;
String length: 23; Contents: 41 6e 6e 61 20 4d 61 72 69 61 20 43 69 63 6d 61 6e 63 6f 76 61 d a ;
String length: 26; Contents: 4d 61 72 69 61 20 52 61 7a 75 73 6f 76 61 20 4d 61 72 74 61 6b 6f 76 61 d a ;
String length: 25; Contents: 4d 69 6c 61 6e 20 52 61 73 74 69 73 6c 61 76 20 50 6f 6b 6f 6a 6e 79 d a ;
String length: 22; Contents: 4d 69 6c 65 6e 61 20 53 65 64 6d 69 6b 72 61 73 6b 6f 76 61 d a ;
String length: 16; Contents: 56 69 6e 63 65 6e 74 20 53 69 6b 75 6c 61 d a ;
String length: 18; Contents: 56 69 6e 63 65 6e 74 20 76 61 6e 20 47 6f 67 68 d a ;
```

As you can see in Linux, there is another character before the NL, a Carriage Return. If anyone can explain this and save me the pain of adding `ifdef` statements for a Linux and Windows code, I'd appreciate it. I understand, that linux appends a Carriage Return after each line, but is this really the intended behaviour when it then gets read by `fgets`?

Comment: CRLF vs NL line endings.  Windows uses two characters, `'\r'` and `'\n'` at the end of a line; Unix uses just `'\n'`.  And on Windows, the I/O system maps the CRLF to `'\n'` only on input, but Linux doesn't because `'\r'` is just another control character to Unix.  (`'\r'` typically maps to control-M or 0x0D; `'\n'` typically maps to control-J or 0x0A.)

Comment: "Of course, buf is the size MAX_LINE_LEN + 1" Not needed: the naximum number of characters read into the buffer is one less than the size you specify, and the line is NUL-terminated. http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fgets.3p.html

Comment: Guessing that not that Linux is adding a CR, but that the CR is in the file data, which to LInux looks like two separate characters, to Windows it's one line-ending character, not sure why fgets represents the way it does though. Can you check the actual file contents

Comment: @Tim Oh yeah, fgets reserves one byte for null, I guess that was a mistype on my part, `buf` *is* actually the size of MAX_LINE_LEN.

Answer (score 4):

MS and Linux has a different expectation of a text file line ending:`"\r\n"` vs `"\n"`.

To cope, recommend after `fgets()` use `strcspn()` to lop off the potential end of line sequence, be it `"\n"`, `"\r\n"` or missing.

```
fgets(buf, MAX_LINE_LEN, f_input);
buf[strcspn(buf, "\n\r")] = '\0';
```

---

Some compilers on Windows will use `"\n"` as the end-of-line sequence  and others use `"\r\n"`.  So I attribute the variation to compilers and their manufacturers more so than the OS.   Also some old MAC text files end with `'\r'` and will foul `fgets()` on Linux.

Further: reading a file that has `"\r\n"` as a *text file* that expects `"\n"` as the end-of-line sequence has a problem when reading a full buffer as `"......\r"` and the line remainder as `"\n"` on the next `fgets()`.  Additional processing is needed to cope as is the case whenever the buffer is insufficient for a *line* of input.

Text files of one variation are often copied to the other platforms, so this is a not-so-rare occurrence.

Due to editing, some text files will have a mixture of line-ending-sequences.

Pedantic code will read the file as binary and process variant line endings itself without `fgets()`.  Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

> As you can see in Linux, there is another character before the NL, a Carriage Return.

That is because your files use CR+LF newlines, i.e. each newline is actually two characters: `"\r\n"`.

If you open files without the `"b"` flag in Windows, its C library will convert each `\n` you write to `\r\n`, and each `\r\n` you read to `\n`.

Use the `"b"` fopen() flag in Windows to see the actual file contents.

When you read a line using `fgets(buf, sizeof buf, handle)`, you can use `buf[strcspn(buf, "\r\n")] = '\0';` to remove the newline.

Comment: I like the use of the `b flag` the most, as it removes the difference between the two platforms. I later remove the newline while copying the string anyways, so this allows me to remove both characters and now works in both windows and linux. Thanks.

Comment: @areuz: You can also use `len = strcspn(buf, "\r\n");` to obtain the length of the line excluding the newline, instead of `len = strlen(buf);`, when copying. If you use a temporary char pointer `char *p = fgets(buf, sizeof buf, f_input);`, you can skip leading whitespace using `p += strspn(p, "\t\n\v\f\r ");` and find the length of the rest of the line excluding newline using `len = strcspn(p, "\r\n");`. There is no `strrcspn()`, so to remove trailing whitespace, you need e.g. `while (len > 1 && isspace(p[len-1])) len--;`. Then, copy just `len` chars starting at `p`.

Answer (score 1):

In C you an open a file stream in *text* or *binary* mode. In binary mode, no translation takes place, and the input and output are the bytes in the file. In text mode, the C "newline" character is translated into what is common on the platform in question. One UNIX-like systems, this is a `0A` byte, and on DOS-like systems this is a `0D` byte followed by a `0A` byte. There are other cases on other operating systems, listed here:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline

So that you don't have to cope with every different text format in every program, these all get translated into an `\n` character as far as the C program sees in the default case (text mode). The input/output layer does the necessary translations for you.

When you use [`fopen()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fopen.3.html) to open a file stream in C for reading or writing, you provide a "file mode" parameter - you're probably using it here as `"r"` to read a file, or `"w"` to write one. If you want to newline translation done you can specify that the stream is opened in *binary* mode, with `"rb"` for reading or `"wb"` for writing.

Comment: "you don't have to cope with every different text format in every program, these all get translated into an `\n` character" is true when reading a text file native to that C program.  The trick is when reading in text mode of a file that originated as some other system's text file.